# (VB.NET) Rotate Bitmap in Image WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, rotation

In the first place I want to clarify that I'm German so please don't mind some of the grammar mistakes I make.

My Problem is that I want to rotate the Bitmap which is shown in an Image-Control in WPF using XAML Code:

```
 <Image Name="ImgDisp"   Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="10,2,10,10" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"     >
        <Image.Source>
            <TransformedBitmap Source="{Binding Path=CurrentImage}" >
                <TransformedBitmap.Transform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                </TransformedBitmap.Transform>
            </TransformedBitmap>
        </Image.Source>
 </Image>
```

The Class the Property is bound looks like this:

```
Public Class PropertyClass

    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
   Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
   Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub




Dim _currentImage As String = ""
Public Property CurrentImage As String
    Get

        Return If(File.Exists(_currentImage), _currentImage, "")

    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _currentImage = value
        CurrentImageName = New FileInfo(value).Name

        NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentImage")
    End Set
End Property


Private Shared _instance As PropertyClass
Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance As PropertyClass
    Get
        If _instance Is Nothing Then _instance = New PropertyClass
        Return _instance
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

The error I got:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in >PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Zeilennummer "97" und Zeilenposition "42" von "Bei der >Initialisierung von "System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TransformedBitmap" wurde eine Ausnahme >ausgelöst.".

What's wrong here? Thank you very much for your help I'm getting really annoyed with this problem.

Comment: You need to bind it to string with relative path to the image located in your project and not with the file name. Also make sure image file is added in your project and `BuildAction` is set to `Resource` for that file.

Comment: The problem with that is that the user changes the image in the image control, so putting it into the ressources is impossible.

I tested it with an image from the project and it works! The question ist how can I achieve this behaviour with the filepath of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you applying your Rotate transform on your Source? Instead Rotate your Image-Control.

Here is the XAML for that :

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=CurrentImage}" x:Name="ImgDisp"   Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="10,2,10,10" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <Image.RenderTransform> 
            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Comment: Because I don't want to rotate the Image control. I want to turn the Bitmap displayed in the Image control.

Maybe as you know it from Windows Photoviewer, where you can turn the Image clockwise and counterclockwise.